# How to use my own classifier in ensemble python

Tags: python, classification, ensemble-learning, sklearn-pandas

The main aim is to add a deep learning classification method like [CNN](https://github.com/Newmu/Theano-Tutorials/blob/master/5_convolutional_net.py) as an individual in ensemble in python.
The following code works fine:

```
   clf1=CNN()   
   eclf1=VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr', clf1)], voting='soft')
   eclf1=eclf1.fit(XTrain,YTrain)
```

But, the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

comes up once running `eclf1=eclf1.predict(XTest)`.

Just in case, The `CNN` consists of `_fit_` function for training, and the following function:

```
def predict_proba(self,XTest):    
    #prediction=np.mean(np.argmax(teY, axis=1) == predict(teX))
    teX=XTest.reshape(len(XTest),3,112,112)
    p=predict(teX) 
    i = np.zeros((p.shape[0],p.max()+1))
    for x,y in enumerate(p):
        i[x,y] = 1 
    return i
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate better what you did and which error you came across?

By your question only I can assume you tried to call 'predic_proba' after the line `eclf1=eclf1.predict(XTest)`. And of course this will turn on an error because the `eclf1.predict(XTest)` returns an array, which doesn't have a predict() method.
Try just changing it to:

```
pred_results=eclf1.predict(XTest)
pred_result_probs = eclf1.predict_proba(XTest)
```